# ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small when using max function

Tags: oracle, plsql

I got **ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small**. But when I run the sql query it only return "T00B " a five character length. It raise an exception when inserting the return max value to the last_account_code. Both last_account_code and account_code is same type.

```
DECLARE 

 last_account_code account_header_1.account_code%TYPE := ''; 
 in_is_delivery_address VARCHAR(1) := 'N';
 starts_with VARCHAR2(1) := 'T';

BEGIN 
 SELECT MAX(account_code)
    INTO last_account_code
   FROM account_header_1
   WHERE account_code like starts_with||'%' AND
         ( account_code like 'FS%' OR in_is_delivery_address <> 'Y' ) AND
         ( account_code not like 'FS%' OR in_is_delivery_address = 'Y' );         

END;
/



-- desc account_header_1;
--
--Name                  Null     Type      
----------------------- -------- --------- 
--ACCOUNT_CODE          NOT NULL CHAR(5)
```

> 6502. 00000 -  "PL/SQL: numeric or value error%s"
>         *Cause:    An arithmetic, numeric, string, conversion, or constraint error
>                occurred. For example, this error occurs if an attempt is made to
>                assign the value NULL to a variable declared NOT NULL, or if an
>                attempt is made to assign an integer larger than 99 to a variable
>                declared NUMBER(2).
>         *Action:   Change the data, how it is manipulated, or how it is declared so
>                that values do not violate constraints.

Comment: What is the character set on you database? If you are using unicode, that char(5) might bring you problems in sizing. Sidenote: don't use varchar(1), use char(1)

Comment: @RenatoAfonso: but shouldn't that be reflected when using `%type`?

Comment: @Abil : Are you able to run this query ,because i cant find any issue with the max account code into the same type .`SELECT MAX(account_code)
    
   FROM account_header_1
   WHERE account_code like 'T'||'%' AND
         ( account_code like 'FS%' OR 'N' <> 'Y' ) AND
         ( account_code not like 'FS%' OR 'N' = 'Y' );    `

Comment: I'll go into more detail then: when you create a char(5), implicitly you're creating a char(5 byte). If you're using unicode (16 bit), it won't fit 5 characters. Either you explicitly create a column char(5 char), or it will always assume bytes.

Comment: @GauravSoni yes I can run the query seperately and it returns "T00B ". But when I tried to execute the same in a block  it raise an exception

Comment: To narrow it down - change the declaration of last_account_code to varchar2(1000), does the code run OK then? Either way, this will tell you where to look next.

Comment: @mathguy the block runs when the size of varchar2(4000)

Comment: @Abil Something with the where clause ,not the max you have mentioned in the question ,and i am sure something with the data in the table.Because i have inserted T00B in the table ,only one record and run the query ,it worked

Comment: @GauravSoni sorry mate i dont think the problem is with the condition because  the same block is running when the size of last_account_code is varchar2(4000)

Comment: OK. Leave the declaration like that for now, and add a `PUT_LINE` command to show you `length(last_account_code)`. What does that show?

Comment: length(last_account_code) shows '5' which is the size of the column account_code in account_header_1 table

Comment: @Abil How come , if you declare a variable with the same data type as your  table ,then it should have the value without any issue , and can you provide output of this query `SELECT max(length(account_code) )
FROM account_header_1 
`

Comment: OK, now I would try again, but with the declaration changed to varchar2(5 byte). Do you get the error message again? How about varchar2(5 char)? It seems more and more like a mismatch there. Someone asked about character set; are you creating the procedure from the same db that hosts the base table?

Comment: @GauravSoni output for this query SELECT max(length(account_code) ) FROM account_header_1 is '5'

Comment: @mathguy Tried again by changing the declaration to varchar2(5) but no luck. And the about procedure creation part, i'm not sure about it. I'm a newbie here. If the procedure created in some other db, would it be a problem?

Comment: @Abil:I suggest to change your datatype to varchar2(5) ,then it will definitely work .Meanwhile let us find why this is not working

Comment: My db's charset is **WE8ISO8859P1**

Comment: @GauravSoni sorry mate I have already tried it but it didnt worked. 
last_account_code varchar2(1000);

Comment: `varchar2(5)` is not the same thing as `varchar2(5 char)`. Also try checking the byte length using `lengthb`, and maybe examine the contents using `dump`.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson lengthb returns 5

Comment: @mathguy procedure and tables are in same DB

Comment: Can you show us a `dump(max(account_code))`?

Comment: @MatthewMcPeak Typ=96 Len=5: 84,48,48,66,32

Comment: Which version of Oracle are you on?  Your code works without error on 12.1, so you are either making a really basic mistake (e.g., "simplifying" your code for posting in some simple way that you don't think matters) or you are encountering a bug.

Comment: Does the anonymous PL/SQL block -- exactly as you posted it -- return the error?  Or is that a simplification of the actual problem code.  For example, is the PL/SQL block being executed in a package defined with invoker's rights (i.e., `authid current_user`), by any chance?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133092/discussion-on-question-by-abil-ora-06502-pl-sql-numeric-or-value-error-chara).

Comment: It works fine in updated version. so it might be a oracle bug  
https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:2322640217906

Comment: **works fine in**   
Oracle Database 10g Release 10.2.0.5.0 - Production
PL/SQL Release 10.2.0.5.0 - Production
"CORE 10.2.0.5.0 Production"
TNS for Linux: Version 10.2.0.5.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 10.2.0.5.0 - Production 
**Problematic version** 
Oracle Database 10g Release 10.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production